# How to dynamically set width & height in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular5

I have created global popup components.I want to set width and height anf title dynamically.How do it?
modal:

```
<app-m [(visible)]="show" title="Modal" data-popup="width:300;height:250">
<h1>Sample Title 1</h1>
<button (click)="show= !show" class="btn">Close</button>
</app-m>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with `decorators`. Pass height, width and title model to `<app-dialog>` like this:

Now in `dialog.component.html` should be:

```
<div [@modal] *ngIf="visible" class="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'width': width+'px', 'height': height+'px'}">
    <b>{{title}}</b>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <button *ngIf="closable" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close" class="cls">X</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="visible" class="overlay" (click)="close()"></div>
```

Comment: Working Good..Thanks

Comment: Sanoj..I have one more question?

Comment: @AppleOrange yes, can you share??

Comment: Sanoj: How we can create own jshint?

Comment: Sanoj: From your example link How we can write code(in typescript) for open same like for close.   After i click button i want to open particular popup.How do it?

Comment: Sanoj:Are you there?

Comment: Sanoj:I am getting you on urgent condition..I need you help to resolve my issue...How can i cantact you immediatly???

Comment: @Apple Orange set function on button click call that function from typescript that's it..

Comment: How to open particular popup only and how to close particular popup?can you update your code in Satckblitz

Comment: I am not able to do that in stackblitz you can also do it.. Declare `showDialog: boolean = false;` in typescript.. And also create a function that contain I have set variable on button click remove from there and put into in function which is to be called.

Comment: Sanoj:pls wait ..i am creating

Comment: Sanoj..If you do not mind can u send ur blog or mail id? because i can i contact u immedialy? or how can i tag my QA to you?

Comment: @AppleOrange currently i don't have any blog. if i give you an email id i am unable to answer immediately??

Comment: It s Ok..If you do not mind..Can you give me your ID? I think that is very useful to improve my angular knowledge

Comment: Sanoj_V:How to show popup always center of the window? after i pressed F12 popup is moving to top..but i want to show always center of the window(page)

Comment: Sanoj_V: I am waiting for your reply..My reputation is decreasing bcoz i am continuesly typing here..please send ur mail id..

Comment: Sanoj: that is possible or not?